# Query Access database and return all records to Excel

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel, vba

I am working on a macro whereby the user enters a search term which is used to query an Access Database. My question is how do I return those records to Excel in separate rows?

For example, a database contains home address information. If the user searches for a zip code, the records that are selected would go into row 1, 2, 3, etc. for as many home addresses as are returned in the query.

Below is some example code - the part I am missing is clearly marked.

I appreciate any help!

```
Sub DatabaseQuery()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim stDB As String, stSQL As String, stProvider As String
Dim SearchTerm As String

stDB = "Data Source= C:\Database.accdb" ' Change accordingly
stProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

With cn
    .ConnectionString = stDB
    .Provider = stProvider
    .Open
End With

SearchTerm = Range("A1").Value ' Change accordingly

stSQL = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 " & _
    "FROM Table1 WHERE Field4= '" & SearchTerm & "'"

rs.Open stSQL, cn, adOpenStatic

' *** Put all the records in Sheet2! *** Help me! :)

cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us which version of Access you're using, as it would change a couple things.

Also, why is there even mention of a connection string? I don't see you saying you're using VB.NET. All I see is MS Access & Excel - Office applications.

When Access exports something to Excel, it would pretty much mimic the same look it did as if you looked at the Data in a DataSheet.

If you **are** using Access, check out this code I wrote as a starting point:

```
outputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\Reports\YourReportName.xlsx"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "YourName", outputFileName, True
```

If you are using a different front end, you need to tell us in your question. Otherwise, how are we supposed to help you? By guessing? That's a good way to not get an answer.

Comment: I am using MS Excel 2010 and MS Access 2010. The majority of the code above I adopted from other posts on SO which works well. That being said, I honestly admit that I don't really understand what it means / what is happening. The code that you wrote is certainly helpful, but I need the code copied into my same workbook - not create a new report.

Comment: check this out: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e9a3203a-450a-4f22-807d-c71c451ed94d/is-it-possible-in-ms-access-to-export-results-of-five-queries-to-one-excel-workbook-via-vba?forum=accessdev)... It has about 3-4 different answers. All which would help you.

Comment: This seems to do the job `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs`

Comment: If it works for you, I am glad you found an alternate solution! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned there is more than 1 way to do this. The following does work for me.

```
Sub DatabaseQuery()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim stDB As String, stSQL As String, stProvider As String
Dim SearchTerm As String

stDB = "Data Source= C:\Database.accdb" ' Change accordingly
stProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

With cn
    .ConnectionString = stDB
    .Provider = stProvider
    .Open
End With

SearchTerm = Range("A1").Value ' Change accordingly

stSQL = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 " & _
    "FROM Table1 WHERE Field4= '" & SearchTerm & "'"

rs.Open stSQL, cn, adOpenStatic

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```